# Make angular-resource ignore server response

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a resource `Post`, and want to be able to mark its items as read. My server only responds with status 200. This leads to angular-resource setting my `Post` items to ['O', 'K'].

How do I tell angular-resource to not set my post items to the server response?

```
var Post = $resource('/api/post/:id/:action', {
  id: '@_id'
}, {
  read: {
    method: 'PUT',
    params: {
      action: 'read'
    }
  }
});


Post.get(function(post) {
  post.$read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation, and skimming thru the source code I didn't find any flag for this. However when using `transformResponse` without returning an object (e.g. `angular.noop`), it seems to be working.

```
var Post = $resource('/api/post/:id/:action', {
  id: '@_id'
}, {
  read: {
    method: 'PUT',
    params: {
      action: 'read'
    },
    transformResponse: angular.noop
  }
});
```